# Drop rows from column that contain a forwardslash python dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop all rows that contain "/" character from a column called event_name

here's my dataframe

```
event_name  
Natalie Cvackova v Josephine Boualem        
E Ymer v Khachanov  Karen Khachanov 
Kuzmanov/Lazov v Koolhof/Middelkoop Kuzmanov/Lazov
Kuzmanov/Lazov v Koolhof/Middelkoop Koolhof/Middelkoop
```

I'm using the following code to do this but it doesn't seem to pick it up maybe do to forwardslash being part of regex

```
df2 = Cov[Cov['event_name'].str.contains("/")]
display(df2)
```

does anybody know how to drop rows that contain fowarslashes based on event name?

Comment: Err, that's a _forward_ slash.

Comment: Also, I guess `Col = Cov[~Cov.event_name.str.contains('/')]` would do.

Comment: `Cov[-Cov.event_name.str.contains('/')]` would do as well.

Comment: Cheers dude. I think that dropped a lot of rows the dataset is smaller now:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an inversion of the condition, using `~`.

```
Cov[~Cov.event_name.str.contains('/')]

                              event_name
0   Natalie Cvackova v Josephine Boualem
1  E Ymer v Khachanov    Karen Khachanov
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your question more precisely (assume dataframe name = df, and column name = event_name):

```
df = df.drop(df[df.event_name.str.contains('/')].index)
```

Comment: add some details in your answer buddy explaining how it solves the problem at hand. This would help the reader understand the solution better.